# bsolenopsis run-tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am testing Solenopsis as new tool for our deployments. I want to trigger some of them using the command-line. As a starting point I want to run all of them using this command:

```
bsolenopsis run-tests
```

but nothing happen, no test were triggered. I am working in a Sandbox.

Comment: Suggest you contact the author(s); not a tool I've seen discussion about on this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to add the min version to do test in a sandbox

solenopsis --apiversion 34.0 run-tests XXXX